# Clean URLs with mod_rewrite trouble

Tags: .htaccess

I have some trouble with my .htacess file.

This code works fine for clean url's.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

But the files that I'm including are not being included because the .htaccess file is making the browser look in the wrong place. For example  if I'm on the page `index/link/` and I'm including from the folder `root/includes`, it looks for folder `root/link/includes`.

Basically it adds an unnecessary step in the link.

I hope someone understands my problem and knows a solution.

Comment: Those two rules can be simplified to just `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.php [L]`

Comment: Secondly: what language are you using? Your includes are usually internal includes relative to .this. location.

Comment: Thanks, knew there was a command like that and I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

When including files, simply do `include __DIR__."/myfile.php";`

`__DIR__` is for the current file directory, so you can then include files RELATIVE to that ABSOLUTE path. Such as `include __DIR__."/../../some_other_file.php";`

Comment: Is this supposed to be added to .htaccess too? because now I'm only including with <?php include(''); ?>

Comment: Okay I figured out how to do it, and it kind of fixed it but the "/" are "\" before the href="" instead and this creates an unreadable url.